# Read line causing a wait for input R

Tags: r

I'm a total noob at R and I may have bitten off a little more than I can chew but if you can help me I will appreciate it.

So what i'm trying to do is retrieve the top trending from twitter (working) and then use them as part of a URL to try pull back their definitions. My issue is the readline function seems to wait for me to hit return before it attempts the URL and i'm looking for a way to make it do the rest automagically, please find my code below

```
definitions <- ""
lapply(X=hashtags,FUN=function(X){
tagdef <- c(tagdefurl,X[[dfPointer]])
tagdef<- paste(tagdef,collapse=" ")
tagdef <- stringr::str_replace(string=tagdef,pattern=" ", replacement="")
definitions <- tryCatch(readline(tagdef),silent=F)
})
```

tagdef is defined as is supposed to be the list to store the returned definitions in

I've checked all my OAuth nonsense and everything on that side is fine, i'm getting the trends back without issue. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: Are you sure you weren't supposed to write `readLines`?

Comment: I'm starting to think i was, just tried ??readLines and it looks like what i was looking for...doh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you might have just stumbled on a case of "user error due to similarly named functions". In R, there is both `readline` (which *reads a line from the terminal (in interactive use)*) and `readLines` (which is used to *read some or all text lines from a connection).

The former expects user input, and the first argument is "`prompt`", hence the waiting for input.

Remember also that cApItaLiZation matters in R.